# MongoDB - How to modify the "key" element in the document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, rename, mongodb-update

I am having the below document structure:

```
[
  {
    "network_type": "ex",
    "rack": [
      {
        "xxxx": {
          "asn": 111111,
          "nodes": {
            "business": [
              "sk550abcc1eb01.abc.com",
              "sk550abcc1eb10.abc.com",
              "sk550abcc1eb19.abc.com",
              "sk550abcc1eb28.abc.com"
            ]
          },
          "region": "ex-01",
          "zone": "01a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to rename/update the key array element "xxxx" to "details".

I tried the below command, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $rename: {
    "rack.xxxx": "details"
  }
})
```

Link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9dcDP-VKZ55

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't direct `$rename` the field name which is within the array.

Instead,

1. Iterate with document(s) in the `rank` array, create the `details` field with the value of `xxxx` and next append this field to each document.
2. Remove the path with `$rank.xxxx` to remove the `xxxx` field from the document(s) in the `rank` array.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      rack: {
        $map: {
          input: "$rack",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                "details": "$$this.xxxx"
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "rack.xxxx"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zs1dPu5n0c1)